# Python 2.7 connection string to PostgreSQL (OOP method)

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I'm new to python and I'm trying to make this work. I'm using Python 2.7 and PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
#! F:\Python2.7.6\python    
import psycopg2

class Database:   
    host = "192.168.56.101"
    user = "testuser"
    passwd = "passwd"
    db = "test"

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect( host = self.host,
                                            user = self.user,
                                            password = self.passwd,
                                            dbname = self.db )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor

    def query(self, q):
        cursor = self.cursor
        cursor.execute(q)
        return cursor.fetchall()

    def __del__(self):
        self.connection.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = Database()
    q = "DELETE FROM testschema.test"
    db.query(q)
```

However I am getting an error "AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'execute'". I figure I should put something like self.execute = something in the Database class, but I can't figure it out what exactly I need to put there. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis at the end

```
self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
```

or

```
cursor = self.cursor()
```

But not both